# Joomla 4x: How to Prevent Modules from Being Wrapped in Div Tags?

Tags: joomla-4.x, module-display, module-style, mod-custom

I am working with Joomla 4 and facing an issue where each module I include gets automatically wrapped in a  tag with a "custom" class, like so:

```
<div id="mod-custom153" class="mod-custom custom">
 Module content
</div>

<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="raw" />
```

**My Solution:**

I am using a module layout called raw.php in my

templates\template_name\html\layouts\chromes\raw.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Get the module
$module = $displayData['module'];

// If the module doesn't have any content, skip (return)
if ($module->content === null || $module->content === '') {
    return;
}

// Output the module content without the surrounding <div>
$pattern = '/<div[^>]*>(.*)<\/div>/s';
preg_match($pattern, $module->content, $matches);
if (!empty($matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
?>
```

it seems to work.

But is there a way to automatically prevent Joomla 4 from wrapping modules in  tags?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapping is specified in the mod_custom tmpl file, ie in modules/mod_custom/tmpl/default.php.

To remove it just create a site template override for mod_custom, and edit the override default.php file to remove the `<div>` wrapper.

(Template overrides are described in [Layout Overrides in Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) and [Joomla Improved Override Management](https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/july-2022/joomla-override-management), for example.)

Comment: Your approach works. In J3 we could remove the outer div with module chrome ovverrides:

function modChrome_raw($module, &$params, &$attribs) { ?>
<?php echo $module->content; ?>
<?php
 
}

Can we no longer do this?

Comment: I did a search for a function called modChrome_raw in the Joomla 4 code base and didn't find anything. But I also didn't find anything in Joomla 3.10 either.